# Image won't show in a <div>

Tags: html, css

Here's my code

HTML:

```
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper"> <!--wrap for all the page-->
            <div id="header"> <!-- div for top part-->
                    <!--<p><img src="image/bannerwithologo.jpg"></p>-->
                <div id="txtlogo"> <!-- inside header for text-->
                    <p>HANA Squad</p>
                </div>

                <div id="menu"> <!-- inside header for menu-->
                    <p href=#>Vidéos</p>
                    <p href=#>Photos</p>
                    <p href=#>Agenda</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        <div id="contenu"> <!-- contents-->
                <div id="welcoming"> <!-- short presentation of the website-->
                </div>
        </div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
.header {background-image: url('../image/banner.jpg');
    height:500px;
    width: 500px;
```

Don't care about the comment in my div header, i was trying something else and didn't erase it

It is not a problem of files directory because if i put the `background-image` in `html` in the css, my image is showing up

I have tried to put different size of my div header but ... Not working

I know it's a stupid problem ..

Comment: you must use an id in your css : `#header {background-image: url('../image/banner.jpg');`

Answer (score 5):

`<div id="header">` you use an id in your code then you have to use a `#` in your css for an id declaration.

```
#header {background-image: url('../image/banner.jpg');
    height:500px;
    width: 500px;
```

for your code you have to set a class for example

`<div class="header">`

Comment: OMG ... I'm tired ... It works ! I didn't thought to check if i used . or # ... Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `header` in your HTML is an id (`id="header"`) yet your CSS is targeting a class (`.header`).

You need to either switch your CSS to target the id, or change your HTML to be a `<div class="header"></div>`.  For what it's worth, it's generally accepted that for more maintainable CSS, you should favour classes over IDs. So I'd go with the latter of the two options.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your Answer

```css
#header {background-image: url('https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png');
    height:500px;
    width: 500px;
  }
```

```html
 <body>
        <div id="wrapper"> <!--wrap for all the page-->
            <div id="header"> <!-- div for top part-->
                    <!--<p><img src="image/bannerwithologo.jpg"></p>-->
                <div id="txtlogo"> <!-- inside header for text-->
                    <p>HANA Squad</p>
                </div>

                <div id="menu"> <!-- inside header for menu-->
                    <p href=#>Vidéos</p>
                    <p href=#>Photos</p>
                    <p href=#>Agenda</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        <div id="contenu"> <!-- contents-->
                <div id="welcoming"> <!-- short presentation of the website-->
                </div>
        </div>

</body>
```